# RegExp not getting everything after the first two new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get everything after the first two `newlines` or `carriage returns`.

I have tried this, but it isn't working. The third item in the array should be 5 lines, but it is only returning the first line after the two newlines. I tried using the `m` modifier but that isn't working either.

What am I missing?

```js
let text = `asdf

asdfsdf
asdf

asdf
23423

dsfddfff`
let matches = text.match(/^.+(\r\n\r\n|\n\n)(.+)/)
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `s` modifier to make the dot match a newline, so that your final group captures *everything* afterwards. Also, when you do that, you'll need to alter the original `^.+` to make it match as *little* as possible, rather than as much as possible - so, make it lazy with `.+?`:

```js
let text = `asdf

asdfsdf
asdf

asdf
23423

dsfddfff`
let matches = text.match(/^.+?(\r\n\r\n|\n\n)(.+)/s)
console.log(matches)
```

Or, for environments that don't support the `s` modifier, use the character set `[\s\S]` to match any character:

```js
let text = `asdf

asdfsdf
asdf

asdf
23423

dsfddfff`
let matches = text.match(/^[\s\S]+?(\r\n\r\n|\n\n)([\s\S]+)/)
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Is it in ecmascript2018 already? I still see the s modifier as stage 4 proposal, unsure where it is already implemented.

Comment: You're right, it's probably too new to rely on fully, I mistakenly assumed it was OK because it worked in my browser.

Comment: I'm using it in node and it is supported there

Comment: Probably a better pattern would be `/(?:r?\n){2}([\s\S]+)/`. I doubt the first `^[\s\S]*?` makes any sense if that substring is not going to  be used.

Comment: another way to match all characters: `[^]`

Comment: @Thomas I don't think `[^]` is great to use because it only works in Javascript (or, at least, is invalid syntax in other common regex flavors) - it can easily lead to confusion, while `[\s\S]`'s meaning should be clear everywhere.